# CMAKE library not linking

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake

Why this code does not produce anything?

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/mylib1)
message("DIR: ${LINK_DIRECTORIES}")
```

I have problem on Windows that though I do `link_directories()` there is NO `-L...` flag when linking. I do create target after `link_directories` command as documentation suggests.

Comment: Please give the full CMakeLists.txt and describe your folder structure - it's really not clear what is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because LINK_DIRECTORIES is not variable, but a directory property. You can obtain it in such way:

```
get_directory_property(OUT_VAR LINK_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "DIR: ${OUT_VAR}")
```

See [documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aget_directory_property).

Answer (score 3):

By using "link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/mylib1)" you are telling CMake to tell the linker to look for libraries in "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/mylib1" when it needs to link against a library with a plain name, as in "png" or "zlib".

Using link_directories is not even recommended anymore, however. We always recommend to use target_link_libraries with the full path name to the library files that you want to link to. Then CMake takes care of arranging all the -L and -l arguments to the linker on all the different platforms for you.

Please add more information to your question if you would like more help. It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do, or what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve overall.

Would target_link_libraries do a better overall job?

```
target_link_libraries( TARGET LIB1 LIB2 LIB3 ... )
```